# Change Question Numbering in Exam Document Class

Tags: numbering, exam

I am using the exam document class to write my math homework. I want to be able to set the specific number for each question. So, for example, when the professor assigns problems 1, 4, 7, 12, I want to have the following:

```
1. some text
4. some text
7. some text
12. some text
```

instead of

```
1. some text
2. some text
3. some text
4. some text.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `\setcounter{question}{3} \question` ... should display question 4.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It worked thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **John Kormylo** for answering this question.

```
\setcounter{question}{n-1} \question
```

displays question n.

---

For example:

```
\setcounter{question}{3} \question
```

displays question 4.