# exam bonus question starting with number 0

Tags: exam

Is it possible to start with the number 0 for a bonus question?

I need this to refer in the test to the collected bonus points by my students during the lecture.

This bonus points should be also shown in grading table.

For "normal" questions it is possible to set the counter (see [Change Question Numbering in Exam Document Class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560131/change-question-numbering-in-exam-document-class)), but not to 0 because this leads to an error in the grading table.

Here an example: (see `\setcounter{question}{-1}`, this leads to the wrong behaviour).

```
% Klausur 22_SoSe_SPO2019
%-----------------------------------------
\documentclass[a4paper,ngerman,12pt,%
% answers,%
twoside]{exam}%-----Klausur Template

%=========================================================
%------------PACOTES
%=========================================================
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[top=2cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.0cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\RequirePackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[sort&compress,square,comma, authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=magenta,citecolor=red,linkcolor=blue,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for simple tables
\usepackage{listings} % for bash display see -https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings
\usepackage{longtable} % longtable support required by pandoc >1.10
\usepackage{booktabs}  % table support for pandoc > 1.12.2
%---Definitionen ---
\newlist{partes}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[partes]{label=(\alph*)}
\newcommand{\parte}{\item}
%---
\newlist{subpartes}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[subpartes]{label=\roman*)}
\newcommand{\subparte}{\item}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{%(
    leftmargin=*, itemsep=12pt, label={\textbf{\arabic*.)}}}
\newcommand{\dis}{\displaystyle}
\renewcommand*\half{.5}
\newcommand\answerbox{%%
    \fbox{\rule{2in}{0pt}\rule[-0.1ex]{0pt}{4ex}}}
    
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  commentstyle=\color{red},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}   

% \bracketedpoints % Points in []
\boxedpoints % points in boxes
% \pointsinrightmargin % Points on the right side
%\pointsinmargin % Points on the left side
\nopointsinmargin % Default Points postion
\setlength\answerlinelength{4cm} % length of the answer line
\setlength\answerskip{1cm} % free space above the answer line

\setlength\linefillheight{1cm} % spacing between the lines of \fillwithlines

\setlength{\gridsize}{5mm} % grid size of \fillwithgrid
\setlength{\gridlinewidth}{0.25pt} % grid line size of \fillwithgrid

\newcommand{\leftanswerline}[1][]%
{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
{\par\hspace{-1.3em}\begin{minipage}{1em}\answerline\end{minipage}}%
{\par\hspace{-1.3em}\begin{minipage}{1em}\answerline[#1]\end{minipage}}%
}

\newcommand\cell[2]{\begin{minipage}[t]{#1\textwidth}#2\vspace{0.2cm}\end{minipage}} 

%=========================================================
%------------Adaption of the exam terms to the language
%=========================================================
    
\pointpoints{Punkt}{Punkte}
\bonuspointpoints{Bonuspunkt}{Bonuspunkte}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Lösung:}%
\enspace}
\chqword{Frage}
\chpgword{Seite}
\chpword{Punkte}
\chbpword{Bonus Punkte}
\chsword{Erreicht}
\chtword{Gesamt}
\hqword{\textcolor{blue}{Aufgabe:}} % point table
\hpword{Punkte:} % point table
\hsword{Ergebnis:}
\htword{\textcolor{blue}{Summe:}}
%=========================================================
%------------General 
%=========================================================
\newcommand{\Hochschule}{xxx}
\newcommand{\Fachbereich}{xxx}
\newcommand{\Fach}{xxx}
\newcommand{\Dozent}{xxx}
\newcommand{\Date}{12.07.2023}%{\today}
\newcommand{\Title}{Klausur in \Fach\ im Sommersemester 2023}
\newcommand{\Duration}{90 Minuten}
\newcommand{\ExamTaker}{Student/in:}
\newcommand{\Grade}{Note:}
%=========================================================
%------------Head- and footnote
%=========================================================
\pagestyle{headandfoot}%{head}%empty
\firstpageheader{}{}{}
\runningheader{\Title}{}{\Date}
\runningheadrule
\firstpagefooter{}{}{}
\runningfooter{}{Viel Erfolg!}{Seite \thepage\ / \numpages}
\runningfootrule
%========================================================
\begin{document}
\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont
%========================================================
%-------------------Headnote of the first page
%========================================================
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}l @{\extracolsep{6pt}}l}
%--------------------Orgão e Turma
\Hochschule & Note: & \answerbox\\
%--------------------Escola/Departamento e Data
\Fachbereich & & \\%Fach:&\Fach\\
%-------------------Disciplina e Professor
Prüfer: \Dozent  &  & \\[8pt]
%-------------------
\ExamTaker\textbf{\hrulefill}& Matrikelnr.:&\textbf{\hrulefill}
%\multicolumn{3}{l}{\ExamTaker \textbf{\hrulefill}}\\
\end{tabular*}
%--------------------LINHA CENTRAL
\begin{center}
\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{1pt}
{\textbf{\Title}}\\
Dauer: \Duration \hspace{9cm}Datum: \Date \\  %\hspace{1cm}/\hspace{1cm}/\hspace{1cm}\\
\vspace{1ex}
\rule[2ex]{\textwidth}{1pt}
\end{center}
%=========================================================
%-------------------Recommendations
%=========================================================
\noindent
\normalsize
Die Klausur umfasst auf \numpages\ Seiten (Vorder- und Rückseite) \numquestions\ Fragethemen mit insgesamt \numpoints\ Punkten. ...
\par
\vspace{0.5cm}
\textbf{WICHTIG:} 
\begin{itemize}
    \item ....
\end{itemize}
%=========================================================
%-------------------Evaluation table
%=========================================================
\begin{center}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
\textbf{Bewertung (wird vom Dozenten ausgefüllt)}\\
\addpoints
\hqword{Aufgabe Nr.:} 
\hpword{Punktzahl:} 
\htword{\textbf{Summe}} 
\hsword{Davon erreicht:}
% \gradetable[h][questions] % horizontale Punktetabelle
\combinedgradetable[h][questions] % horizontale Punktetabelle inkl. Bonus
%\multicolumngradetable{1}[test]
\end{center}
    
\begin{questions}
    \setcounter{question}{-1} \bonusquestion \textbf{Keine Prüfungsaufgabe!} Ihm Rahmen der Vorlesung wurden Bonuspunkte für die Bearbeitung der Aufgaben verteilt. Diese werden durch durch den Aufgabenblock 1 dokumentiert. 
    \begin{parts}
        \bonuspart[9] Aufgabe 1
        \bonuspart[4\half] Aufgabe 2
        \bonuspart[4\half] Aufgabe 3
    \end{parts}

\noindent
\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{1pt} 

\subsection*{Aufgaben}

\question[1] First task...
\question[1] Second task...
\question[1] Third
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows why setting the counter to zero (or -1) does not work here.

Comment: I think, this is only possible with a lot of patching. I am unsure whether it is a good idea to do this, actually. The package does not really allow for this.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the example, I hope it helps to understand my problem. Alternatively, it would be also fine for me to mention the bonus points in the grading table without an explicit question.